# Assigning properties to non-prototype with decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I am building a simple mapping between frontend/backend data structure. In order to do that I've created a decorator that looks like the following:

```
function ApiField(
    apiKey: string,
    setFn: (any) => any = (ret) => ret,
    getFn: (any) => any = (ret) => ret
) {
    return function (target: AbstractModel, propertyKey: string) {
        target.apiFieldsBag = target.apiFieldsBag || {};
        _.assign(
            target.apiFieldsBag,
            {
                [propertyKey]: {
                    apiKey: apiKey,
                    setFn: setFn,
                    getFn: getFn
                }
            }
        );
    };
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
class AbstractCar {
    @ApiField('id')
    public id: string = undefined;
}

class BMW extends AbstractCar {
    @ApiField('cylinders')
    public cylinderCount: number;
}

class VW extends AbstractCar {
    @ApiField('yearCompanyFounded')
    public yearEstablished: number;
}
```

The issue that I'm seeing is that instead of the actual object being passed to the decorator it's always its prototype:

```
__decorate([
    ApiField('yearCompanyFounded')
], VW.prototype, "yearEstablished", void 0);
```

Which means that as I am assigning stuff to the instance in the decorator, it is always attached to the prototype which in turn means that properties I want to be defined only the `VW` instance are also available on the `AbstractCar` and the `BMW` class (in this example this would be `yearEstablished`). This makes it impossible to have two properties with the same name but different API fields in two different classes.

Is there any way to circumvent this behaviour?

Comment: As an aside, you don’t need the `target.apiFieldsBag =` in front of `_.assign(`. You also have the option to use ES6 `Object.assign()` instead of `_.assign()`.

Comment: Yeah I figured that as I looked over the question again. Thanks for the heads up anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, all three classes are adding properties to the same object. The key to fix this is to **clone** the object on `target.data` so that each class is using a different object instead of all of them referring to the same object.

Here's a simpler example that demonstrates one way of doing this:

```
function ApiField(str: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        // I tested with Object.assign, but it should work with _.assign the same way
        target.data = _.assign({}, target.data, {
            [propertyKey]: str
        });
    };
}

class AbstractCar {
    @ApiField("car")
    public carID;
}

class BMW extends AbstractCar {
    @ApiField("bmw")
    public bmwID;
}

class VW extends AbstractCar {
    @ApiField("vw")
    public vwID;
}

AbstractCar.prototype.data; // Object {carID: "car"}
BMW.prototype.data;         // Object {carID: "car", bmwID: "bmw"}
VW.prototype.data;          // Object {carID: "car", vwID: "vw"}
```

Comment: The thing is, I want the BMW Class to inherit the data from the AbstractCar

Comment: @justNik ah, ok. I updated my answer with something that works for that.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Funny how such a complicated looking thing boils down to such a common javascript problem. Talk about missing the forrest for the trees

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `public` inside a class is not standard JavaScript, it’s only something that TypeScript does. Therefore, you have to be careful, because anything you do may break in the future.

One possibility is to use `Object.assign()` to add instance properties (IINM, `apiFieldsBag` should be transferred from the object created by the object literal to `this`):

```
class AbstractCar {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, {
            @ApiField('id')
            id: undefined,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually using typescript, so using `public` should be fine :) But I am going to give your solution a try

Comment: @justNik I know that `public` is TypeScript. The problem with `public foo = x` is that it doesn’t exist as an actual entity (e.g. a property), it is compiled to an assignment in the constructor. Therefore, it isn’t clear what should be decorated, because, ATM, only classes and properties can be decorated.

Comment: @justNik I just looked at the code that a decorated `public` is compiled to and TypeScript does indeed decorate a property of the prototype. That’s a bug, IMO (it should decorate a property of `this` in the constructor) – you may want to file a bug report.

Comment: Ah now I understood what you meant. But yes I agree on the bug part, I will file that :)

Comment: @AxelRauschmayer it's not a bug as the spec says it should be the prototype... babel works the same way. Also, the access modifier doesn't affect the output. It's a compile time only aspect of the language.

Comment: @DavidSherret TypeScript translates `public foo = 123;` to `this.foo = 123` in the constructor. Decorating `TheClass.prototype.foo` if you decorate `public foo` is not correct. See what the following code is translated to: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20TheClass%20%7B%0A%09%40TheAnnotation%0A%09public%20foo%20%3D%20123%3B%0A%7D

Comment: @AxelRauschmayer that's [expected behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2249) for properties (see [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20TheClass%20%7B%0D%0A%09%40TheAnnotation%0D%0A%09foo%20%3D%20123%3B%0D%0A%7D) too). Decorators on class members are called when the class is declared. Also, it's not decoratorating `TheClass.prototype.foo` per se. At declaration it calls a decorator that is passed the class' prototype and property name as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I’ll dig through it once I have time. I would not call `foo` a class member (`TheClass.foo`), it’s an instance property (`new TheClass().foo`). It’s not a prototype property (`TheClass.prototype.foo`), either.

Comment: @AxelRauschmayer sorry, I was using the term in a general sense (from my [c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx) background); however, it is used this same way on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and in the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-privatepublic-modifiers), so I think I'll keep using it. Generally I would use the term class member, then to get more specific specify instance member or static member as the TypeScript Handbook does. Anyway, this is a bit off topic :)